# Gurobi in Python: best way to read csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, gurobi

I'm learning how to solve combinatorial optimization problems in Gurobi using Python. I would like to know what is the best option to read a csv file to use the data as model parameters. I'm using 'genfromtxt' to read the csv file, but I'm having difficulties in using it for constraint construction (Gurobi doesn't support this type - see error).

Here my code and error message, my_data is composed by 4 columns: node index, x coordinate, y coordinate and maximum degree.

```
from gurobipy import *
from numpy import genfromtxt
import math

# Read data from csv file
my_data = genfromtxt('prob25.csv', delimiter=',')

# Number of vertices
n = len(my_data)

# Function to calculate euclidean distancces
dist = {(i,j) :
    math.sqrt(sum((my_data[i][k]-my_data[j][k])**2 for k in [1,2]))
    for i in range(n) for j in range(i)}

# Create a new model
m = Model("dcstNarula")

# Create variables

vars = m.addVars(dist.keys(), obj=dist, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='e')
for i,j in vars.keys():
    vars[j,i] = vars[i,j] # edge in opposite direction

m.update()

# Add degree-b constraint
m.addConstrs((vars.sum('*',j) <= my_data[:,3]
             for i in range(n)), name='degree')

GurobiError: Unsupported type (<type 'numpy.ndarray'>) for LinExpr addition argument
```

First two lines of data

```
1,19.007,35.75,1
2,4.4447,6.0735,2
```

Comment: Show the first two lines of ```my_data```.

Comment: 1,19.007,35.75,1
   2,4.4447,6.0735,2

Comment: Add those two lines in code-mode to your question. It's  less useful with broken-format within a comment. **Edit:** so no header i suppose?

Comment: No (I am really new and learning how to use stackoverflow, sorry)

Comment: Double-check your *Add degree-b constraint*. This does not make any sense to me! i from loop is unused, so you are doing the same operation n times. j maybe undefined...

Comment: And after you checked this, replace ```my_data[:,3]``` with ```my_data[:,3].tolist()```.

Comment: I used `j` instead of `i`, put even after changing it (and also putting `my_data[:,3].tolist`) I am having the same problem

Comment: Actually, I got another message `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'`

Comment: Then add this error and a full traceback (it will show the line) to your question as edit. And also show the modified code. Look at other questions to see what a good procedure is to get more help.

Comment: I realize I forgot to put the index in `my_data[:,3]` as `my_data[i,3]`. A really stupid error. But thank you a lot for your patience. How can I mark the question as solved??

Comment: You can't without some answer. I recommend writing the answer yourself, with a good explanation of the solution. Not sure if you can accept it yourself with your status though.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was a problem of indexing instead of data type. In the code:

```
# Add degree-b constraint
m.addConstrs((vars.sum('*',j) <= my_data[:,3]
         for i in range(n)), name='degree')
```

It should be used `vars.sum('*',i)` instead of `vars.sum('*',j)` and `my_data[i,3]` instead of `my_data[:,3]`

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is answered, for future visitors who are looking for good ways to read a csv file, pandas must be mentioned:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('prob25.csv', header=None, index_col=0, names=['x', 'y', 'idx'])
df
         x        y  idx
1  19.0070  35.7500    1
2   4.4447   6.0735    2
```